# How to convert from []byte to int in Go Programming

Tags: tcp, client-server, byte, type-conversion, go

I need to create a client-server example over TCP. In the client side I read 2 numbers and I send them to the server. The problem I faced is that I can't convert from `[]byte` to `int`, because the communication accept only data of type `[]byte`.

Is there any way to convert `[]byte` to `int` or I can send `int` to the server?

Some sample code will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify the task, are you writing both the client and the server code?  And are both written in Go?

Comment: AFAIK you have to do bit shift.

Comment: To send data to the network it needs to be in byte form.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use encoding/binary's [ByteOrder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) to do this for 16, 32, 64 bit types

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/g9ZQxiDYJu)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/binary"

func main() {
    var mySlice = []byte{244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244, 244}
    data := binary.BigEndian.Uint64(mySlice)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by offsets?  as in, reading from the middle of a []byte?  just do BigEndian.Uint64(bigSlice[10:18]) (basically, read the bytes in the middle of the slice.  or do you mean something else?

Comment: Ya, I figured after asking the stupid question. Just can't edit it :D Thanks though.

Comment: It  returns uint16, uint32, unit64 but not int. Need to convert to int from uint

Comment: Sort of obvious, but not at first when just wanting to go byte[] to int: this does not work for a case where the byte array is very small. For one of my cases I have a byte array with only 2 elements, and the `Uint64` method fails at this line in source `_ = b[7] // bounds check hint to compiler; see golang.org/issue/14808`, since obviously the index is out of bounds. I needed the `Uint16` method.

Comment: @TinkalGogoi use int64(value) to convert a value to an int64.

Answer (score 22):

If []byte is ASCII byte numbers then first convert the []byte to string and use the `strconv` package `Atoi` method which convert string to int.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    byteNumber := []byte("14")
    byteToInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(byteNumber))
    fmt.Println(byteToInt)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gEzxva8-BGP)

Comment: parsing an int to a string, then to a byte array and reverse looks like a too long way

Comment: Yes, a byte to int would be less expensive but haven't found a way.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from a byte array you can use the [binary package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) to do the conversions.

For example if you want to read ints :

```
buf := bytes.NewBuffer(b) // b is []byte
myfirstint, err := binary.ReadVarint(buf)
anotherint, err := binary.ReadVarint(buf)
```

The same package allows the reading of unsigned int or floats, with the desired byte orders, using the general [Read](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) function.

Comment: Varint is specific for protocol buffers and is probably not what you're looking for. Spec: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html

Comment: Just to clarify, a 32 bit integer may use up to 5 bytes after encoded by Varint.

Comment: This doesn't work for the OP's use case. Use `binary.Read()` instead. See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15945/effectively-convert-little-endian-byte-slice-to-int32

Answer (score 10):

```golang
now := []byte{0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF}
nowBuffer := bytes.NewReader(now)
var  nowVar uint32
binary.Read(nowBuffer,binary.BigEndian,&nowVar)
fmt.Println(nowVar)
```

```golang
4294967295
```

Answer (score 9):

The `math/big` provides a simple and easy way to convert a binary slice to a number
[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/MEzhp3bcyI6)

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)
func main() {

    b := []byte{0x01, 0x00, 0x01}

    v := int(big.NewInt(0).SetBytes(b).Uint64())

    fmt.Printf("%v", v)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For encoding/decoding numbers to/from byte sequences, there's the [encoding/binary](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) package. There are examples in the documentation: see the Examples section in the table of contents.

These encoding functions operate on [io.Writer](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) interfaces. The [net.TCPConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn) type implements io.Writer, so you can write/read directly to network connections.

If you've got a Go program on either side of the connection, you may want to look at using [encoding/gob](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/). See the article "[Gobs of data](http://golang.org/doc/articles/gobs_of_data.html)" for a walkthrough of using gob (skip to the bottom to see a self-contained example).

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use gob in a TCP application?

Comment: I've added a link to an article that describes gobs; you can skip to the bottom if you just want to see a code example. When you construct an encoder/decoder, you can just pass in the `*TCPConn` as the argument to `gob.NewEncoder`/`gob.NewDecoder`.

Answer (score 3):

Using bitwise operator without additional dependencies

```
func toInt(bytes []byte) int {
    result := 0
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        result = result << 8
        result += int(bytes[i])

    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If bytes in the `[]byte` array are ASCII characters from 0 to 9 you can convert them to an `int` in a loop:

```golang
var value int
for _, b := range []byte{48, 49, 50, 51, 52} {
    value = value*10 + int(b-48)
}
fmt.Printf("integer value: %d", value)
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IyVJ0uIN81c)

Answer (score 0):

`binary.Read` in `encoding/binary` provides mechanisms to convert byte arrays to datatypes.

Note that Network Byte Order is [BigEndian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997571/big-endian-or-little-endian-on-net), so in this case, you'll want to specify `binary.BigEndian`.

```
  package main

  import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
  )

  func main() {
    var myInt int
    b := []byte{0x18, 0x2d} // This could also be a stream
    buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &myInt) // Make sure you know if the data is LittleEndian or BigEndian
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print(myInt)
  }
```

Reviewing this documentation may be helpful: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary@go1.17.1#Read